# React eventsource is not closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-sent-events

I'm quite new to web development and server-sent-events in particular so probably I'm missing something obvious. I'm trying to display a logger on a React page with server-sent-events, which works fine, but I cannot close the eventSource. The server continuously receives requests after eventSource.close() was called.

```
  const [eventSource, setEventSource] = React.useState(new EventSource("http://localhost:5001/logs"))
  const [logs, setLogs] = React.useState([])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    eventSource.onmessage = e => updateLogs((e.data))

    return (() => eventSource.close() )
  }, [])

  const updateLogs = (entry) => {
    setLogs(logs => [...logs, entry])
    if (entry === 'finished'){
      eventSource.close()
      console.log('closed eventsource')
      setEventSource(null)
    }
  }
```

The console logs "closed eventsource" as expected and the logs hook is not updated any longer, but the requests keep getting fired from somewhere. What am I missing?

The requests are handled by a flask server like this (just send some dummy logs):

```
def log_progress():
  for i in range(10):
    message = 'data: step {} \n\n'.format(i)
    yield message
    time.sleep(1)
  yield 'data: finished\n\n'

@app.route("/logs")
def stream_logs():
    return = Response(log_progress(), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

The server log:

```
<Response streamed [200 OK]>
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Oct/2020 11:00:22] "GET /logs HTTP/1.1" 200 -
<Response streamed [200 OK]>
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Oct/2020 11:00:22] "GET /logs HTTP/1.1" 200 -
<Response streamed [200 OK]>
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Oct/2020 11:00:22] "GET /logs HTTP/1.1" 200 -
<Response streamed [200 OK]>
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Oct/2020 11:00:23] "GET /logs HTTP/1.1" 200 -
<Response streamed [200 OK]>
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Oct/2020 11:00:23] "GET /logs HTTP/1.1" 200 -
// this keeps on forever until page is closed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found a workaround (I still don't understand why the initial approach did not work, though).  Instead of using a hook to store the eventListener, I handled everything in the useEffect hook that is called on mount using addEventListener():

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let eventSource = new EventSource("http://localhost:5001/logs")
    // eventSource.onmessage = event => updateLogs((event.data))
    eventSource.addEventListener('newEntry', e =>
      updateLogs(e.data)
    )
    eventSource.addEventListener('close', () =>
      eventSource.close()
    )

    return (() => eventSource.close() )
  }, [])
```

And on the server, I've added event types:

```
def log_progress():
  for i in range(10):
    message = 'event: newEntry\n'
    message += 'data: step {} \n\n'.format(i)
    yield message
    time.sleep(1)
  yield 'event: close\ndata: finished \n\n'
@app.route("/logs")
def stream_logs():
    return = Response(log_progress(), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```